# Getting INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY on validation of changeset

Tags: apex

I am getting the error below when I try to validate my changeset.  Below that is the test method... Can some point me in the right direction?

> Test_CC_BeazerLot_TriggerMethods.testHandleOwnerChange() Class 177 1 Failure Message: "System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0iC0000005ies8IAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, BeazerLot_Close: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owne...

```
private static testMethod void test_handleLotClosure() {

     // Create test account with co buyer info
     Account acc1 = new Account(lastname='ACC1LAST', firstname='ACC1FIRST', personEmail='test@test.test', CoBuyerLastName__c = 'CB1LAST', CoBuyerFirstName__c = 'CB1FIRST', recordTypeID = CC_BeazerLot_TriggerMethods.PERSON_RECORD_TYPE, cobuyerEmail__c = 'test@test.test');
     insert acc1;

     CoContact__c cc1 = new CoContact__c(CoContactAccount__c = acc1.id, CoContactfirstname__c = 'CC1FIRST', CoContactlastname__c='CC1LAST', CoContactemail__c = 'test@test.com');
     insert cc1;
     CoContact__c cc2 = new CoContact__c(CoContactAccount__c = acc1.id, CoContactfirstname__c = 'CC2FIRST', CoContactlastname__c='CC2LAST', CoContactemail__c = 'test@test.com');
     insert cc2;

     // Create test lot, referencing the above account, but is not closed
     BeazerLot__c lot1 = new BeazerLot__c(name='0054', status__c = 'Spec House', accountname__c = acc1.id);
     insert lot1;
     // Ensure no lot relationships were created
     List<CC_LotRelationship__c> lot1Rels = [SELECT id, accountname__c FROM cc_lotrelationship__c WHERE BeazerLot__c = :lot1.id];
     System.assertEquals(0, lot1Rels.size());
     Test.startTest();

     lot1.status__c = 'Closed';
     update lot1;

     Test.stopTest();

     // Should now have 4 lot relationships
     lot1Rels = [SELECT id, accountname__c, accountname__r.firstname, accountname__r.lastname, NHCCContactPriority__c FROM cc_lotrelationship__c WHERE BeazerLot__c = :lot1.id];
     System.assertEquals(4, lot1Rels.size());

     lot1 = [SELECT id, accountname__c, accountname__r.cobuyerlastname__c, accountname__r.cobuyerfirstname__c, keycontact1name__c, keycontact1name__r.accountname__c, keycontact2name__c, keycontact2name__r.accountname__r.firstname, keycontact2name__r.accountname__r.lastname FROM BeazerLot__c WHERE id = :lot1.id];

     // Assert that the KeyContact1 and KeyContact2 fields have been populated correctly
     for (CC_LotRelationship__c loopLR : lot1Rels) {
          if (loopLR.NHCCContactPriority__c == CC_BeazerLot_TriggerMethods.KEY_CONTACT_1 ) {
               System.assertEquals(lot1.keycontact1name__c, loopLR.id);
          }
          if (loopLR.NHCCContactPriority__c == CC_BeazerLot_TriggerMethods.KEY_CONTACT_2 ) {
               System.assertEquals(lot1.keycontact2name__c, loopLR.id);
          }

     }

     // Assert that the account names are correct
     System.assertEquals(lot1.accountname__c, lot1.keycontact1name__r.accountname__c);
     System.assertEquals(lot1.accountname__r.cobuyerlastname__c , lot1.keycontact2name__r.accountname__r.lastname);
     System.assertEquals(lot1.accountname__r.cobuyerfirstname__c, lot1.keycontact2name__r.accountname__r.firstname);

}


public static void handleOwnerChange(Map<ID, BeazerLot__c> newMapOfLots, Map<ID, BeazerLot__c> oldMapOfLots) {
    if(trn_TransactionVariables.lotRelationshipTriggerRunning) 
        return; 

    // Read through all incoming records to establish a) the lot ID and b) the account ID (including the old account) 
    List<ID> listOfLotIDs = new List<ID>(); 
    Set<ID> setOfAccountNewIDs = new Set<ID>(); 
    Set<ID> setOfAccountOldIDs = new Set<ID>(); 
    for (BeazerLot__c newLot : newMapOfLots.values()) {
        BeazerLot__c oldLot = oldMapOfLots.get(newLot.Id); 
        if (newLot.AccountName__c != null && newLot.AccountName__c != oldLot.AccountName__c && oldLot.Status__c == CLOSED_STATUS) {
            listOfLotIDs.add(newLot.Id); 
            setOfAccountNewIDs.add(newLot.Accountname__c); 
            if(oldLot.Accountname__c != null){
                setOfAccountOldIDs.add(oldLot.Accountname__c); 
            } 
        }
    }   

    if (listOfLotIDs.isEmpty()) 
        return; 

    // Create lists for the records we may be creating later 
    list<CC_LotRelationship__c> lotRelationsNew = new list<CC_LotRelationship__c>(); 
    map<Id,CC_LotRelationship__c> lotRelationsToUpdate = new map<Id,CC_LotRelationship__c>();
    Map<Id, Account> Accts = new Map<Id, Account>([select Id, PersonContactId from Account where Id in :setOfAccountNewIDs]); 



    // Get Lots and their relations 
    list<BeazerLot__c> Lots = [SELECT Id, Status__c, Accountname__c, Accountname__r.Firstname, Accountname__r.Lastname, accountname__r.PersonContactId, (SELECT Id, Accountname__c, Contactname__c, Accountname__r.Firstname, Accountname__r.Lastname, LotRelationshipType__c FROM CC_Lot_Relationships__r) FROM BeazerLot__c WHERE Id IN :listOfLotIDs]; 

    // Update Existing Lot Relationship 
    for (BeazerLot__c enhancedLot : Lots) { 
        for (CC_LotRelationship__c LotRelationship : enhancedLot.CC_Lot_Relationships__r) { 
            if(setOfAccountNewIDs.contains(LotRelationship.AccountName__c)) 
                lotRelationsToUpdate.put(LotRelationship.Accountname__c,new CC_LotRelationship__c(Id=LotRelationship.Id,LotRelationshipType__c=OWNER));
            if(setOfAccountOldIDs.contains(LotRelationship.AccountName__c)) 
                lotRelationsToUpdate.put(LotRelationship.Accountname__c,new CC_LotRelationship__c(Id=LotRelationship.Id,LotRelationshipType__c=PREVIOUS_OWNER)‌​); 
        } 
    } 

    // Add New Lot Relationship 
    for (BeazerLot__c Lot : Lots) { 
        if(!lotRelationsToUpdate.containsKey(Lot.AccountName__c) && Accts.containsKey(newMapOfLots.get(Lot.Id).AccountName__c)) 
            lotRelationsNew.add(new CC_LotRelationship__c( Name = newMapOfLots.get(Lot.Id).Accountname__r.Name, AccountName__c = newMapOfLots.get(Lot.Id).AccountName__c, LotRelationshipType__c = OWNER, ContactName__c = Accts.get(newMapOfLots.get(Lot.Id).Accountname__c).PersonContactId, BeazerLot__c = Lot.Id)); 
    } 


    for (CC_LotRelationship__c lr:lotRelationsToUpdate.values()) {
        lotRelationsNew.add(lr); 
    }

    trn_TransactionVariables.lotRelationshipTriggerRunning = true; 
    upsert lotRelationsNew; 
    trn_TransactionVariables.lotRelationshipTriggerRunning = false; 
}
```

> EDIT

Trigger Code

```
 trigger BeazerLot_Close on BeazerLot__c (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) { 

        if (trn_TransactionVariables.isInCCRollup) 
             return; 
        if (SysConfigs.IsDeactivatedForWFT) 
             return; 
        if (Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) 
             CC_BeazerLot_TriggerMethods.setOriginalOwnerOnLotClosure(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap); 
        if (trn_TransactionVariables.isLotClosing) {
             if (Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
                  CC_BeazerLot_Close.handleLotClosure(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
             }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Could you post the error message in it's entirety?  Its cut off

Comment: You'll have to post your trigger (class helper methods) code as well.

Comment: Failure Message: "System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0iC0000005ies9IAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, BeazerLot_Close: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owne...

Comment: Thats the way it was.. I believe it is supposed to say ownerID cannot be blank

Comment: So have you tried adding an OwnerId?

Comment: Here is the trigger code:

Comment: The trigger code is less valuable that than these methods, which is where your code is bombing: setOriginalOwnerOnLotClosure and handleLotClosure

Comment: Per @greenstork, the methods are really where your code is bombing and what we really need to see in order to help

Comment: I added the method to the question

Comment: Dunc44, if the text is too long and you need to correspond by email please reach me at shawn.king@beazer.com

Comment: I ran the ApexTestExecution in Production and it failed but was successful in Test Sandbox.  this is the error only in Prod:

Comment: Time Started 9/19/2013 8:21 AM
Class Test_CC_BeazerLot_TriggerMethods
Method Name test_handleLotClosureNoCobuyer
Pass/Fail Fail
Error Message System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0iC0000005ifLXIAY; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, BeazerLot_Close: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]

Class.CC_BeazerLot_Close.handleLotClosure: line 284, column 1
Trigger.BeazerLot_Close: line 11, column 1: []